# How to convert decorator @action to non-decorator action in MobX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am removing decorators from my React Native app (too many issues with babel) and my actions are not working (the contained function does not run).

I'm translating class actions e.g.

```
class MyStore {
  //...

  @action 
  myAction(param) {
    //...
  }
}
```

To

```
class MyStore {
  //...

  myAction(param) {
    action("Perform action with param", (param) => {
      //...
    })
  }
}
```

What's the correct way to convert a class @action to the non-decorator form?

Comment: Should you really use class if you are removing babel? You could do `var myStore = { myAction: action(function() { ... }) };`.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how the `var myStore` form would look with `extendObservable`.

Comment: I guess they would just become separate `observable` properties of the object.

Comment: You could checkout mattruby's [**mobx-examples**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-examples/blob/master/mobx-standalone/50-action/demo.js) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define action as

```
class MyStore {
  //...

  myAction = action(param => {
    //...
  });
}
```

or use `runInAction()`

```
class MyStore {
  //...

  myAction(param) {
    runInAction(() => {
      //...
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What's the correct way to convert a class @action to the non-decorator form?

Decorators evaluate to function calls at runtime, so simply calling them manually would be the most straightforward thing to do. `@action` is a method decorator, and method decorators take the following arguments at runtime:

1. The class prototype for instance methods (constructor function for static methods)
2. The method name (property key)
3. The property descriptor of the method

With that in mind, you can simply do:

```
class MyStore {
    myAction(param) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Apply the @action decorator manually:
action(MyStore.prototype, "myAction");
```

or:

```
action(MyStore.prototype, "myAction", Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyStore.prototype, "myAction"));
```

If you do this immediately after the class declaration, the result should be completely identical to that by using decorators, without having to use the decorator syntax.

Comment: This is a really informative answer, however decouples the `action` assignment from the class method declaration so not quite as maintainable as @farwayer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use makeAutoObservable?

```
 import { makeObservable, observable, action } from 'mobx';

class MyStore {
 someValue = 0;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)

  myAction(param) {
    // Your action code here
    this.someValue = param;
  }
}
```